# Create function centuryFromYear($year) in php language?

Tags: php

I want create function to execute this task in PHP Language
**Given a year, return the century it is in. The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200, etc.

```
Example

For year = 1905, the output should be
centuryFromYear(year) = 20;
For year = 1700, the output should be
centuryFromYear(year) = 17**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ceil()` for this:

```
<?php

function getCentury($year) 
{
    return ceil($year / 100);
}

echo getCentury(2005);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/854182

Output is :

```
For 1900 : 19
For 1901 : 20
For 1999 : 20
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Comment: Shouldn't it not be `ceil(($year + 1)/100);` ?

Comment: @Philipp : In which case it is failing ?

Comment: I.e. for 100 - I think this should be 2 instead of 1

Comment: `The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200`

Comment: `0-100` it will be `1` and for `101-200` it will be `2`

Comment: Apparently, there's a [debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century#Debate_over_century_celebrations) over this, so @user2486 function is correct according to OP's "side" on this.